# Mysql query to delete woocommerce products in certain category

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

We need to delete ~20.000 products that are in a certain category. We would like to do that by mysql directly.
With that query, all products get deleted:

```
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id IN 
(SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation'));
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN 
('product','product_variation'));
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation');
```

How can we just delete products inside category XY?

Thanks for help

Comment: Just to observe, it's sometimes quicker to create a new table, retaining only those rows you wish to keep, and then replacing the old table with the new one.

Comment: Yes, but we have ~60.000 products in general

Comment: Yes. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: I get you, but we still do not have a the query to run on that new table.

Comment: Sure, but either way, start by writing a SELECT that returns all relevant data (or either the data you want to keep, or the data you want to DELETE) from all relevant tables.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but exactly that is the question, not how to operate with dummy tables.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of a query...

```
SELECT r*
     , p.*
     , m.*
  FROM wp_term_relationships r
  JOIN wp_posts p
    ON p.id = r.object_id 
  JOIN wp_postmeta m
    ON m.post_id = p.id 
 WHERE p.post_type IN ('product','product_variation');
```